# need <h:selectBooleanCheckbox for rerender a form

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, render, rerender

I have a <h:form id="updateForm">. Inside of this form I have <h:selectedBooleanCheckbox > and <rich:extendedDataTable id="searchTable">.
All I want is when I click on the checkbox rerender the searchTable.

I am using Java and JSF.

Can somebody help me?

My checkbox is :

```
<h:selectedBooleanCheckbox value="Submit" action="#{actions.submitToDB}">
  <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="searchTable" />
</h:selectedBooleanCheckbox >
```